# Binomial Cumulative Distribution probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If you were to do a thing $x$ times, and 35% of the time it worked, what's the chance that after $x$ times it would have worked 240 or more times?

Comment: That depends on how many trials there were... if at least $240/0.35$, 1; if less, 0.

Comment: Between 240 and 685. And I'm confused by your comment, 686 times would not lead to a 100% chance, right?

Comment: It isn't clear from your question if you are asking about the trials _done_ or a _new_ set of trials...

Comment: I just edited it. How about now?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are describing a random variable $X\sim B(x,0.35)$. Using the known PMF (probability mass function) of the binomial distribution we have:

$$P(X=\alpha)={x \choose \alpha}\left(0.35\right)^{\alpha}(0.65)^{x-\alpha}$$

Therefore, we have:

$$P(X\geq 240)=1-P(X\lt 239)=1-\sum_{\alpha=0}^{239}{{x \choose \alpha}\left(0.35\right)^{\alpha}(0.65)^{x-\alpha}}$$

Which depends on the value of your variable $x$.

Comment: Do have a calculator where I could put this in?

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum) to compute the summation, and then just subtract the answer from $1$ to give you your final result.

Comment: I tried [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum&a=*C.sum-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=%280.35%29%5Ea*%280.65%29%5E%28400-a%29&f=Sum.sumfunction_%280.35%29%5Ea*%280.65%29%5E%28400-a%29&f3=a&f=Sum.sumvariable_a&f4=0&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit_0&f5=239&f=Sum.sumupperlimit_239) but it doesn't seem to be the right formula

Comment: @Cool12309 That is because you forgot to include the binomial co-efficient: $$\binom{400}{\alpha}$$ The correct sum is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum&a=*C.sum-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=%28400+choose+a%29+%280.35%29%5Ea*%280.65%29%5E%28400-a%29&f=Sum.sumfunction_%28400+choose+a%29+%280.35%29%5Ea*%280.65%29%5E%28400-a%29&f3=a&f=Sum.sumvariable_a&f4=0&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit_0&f5=239&f=Sum.sumupperlimit_239).

Comment: I subtracted that from 1, but that would give a crazy low chance. I thought it would be much higher than that?

Comment: @Cool12309 If you look at the mean of the random variable you get $E[X]=400\times 0.35=140$, so a very low value for $P(X\geq 240)$ is to be expected.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense, is this the chance that out of 400 trials, 240 or more would be successful?

Comment: @Cool12309 Yes, it is the chance that out of $400$ Bernoulli trials, where each trial has a probability of success $0.35=35\%$, more than $240$ are successful.

Comment: But shouldn't it be way higher than it is? I just don't get it. Even 500 it's extremely low.